# Logback SpringProperties read before Spring Cloud Config results in error

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud-config

I have a logback-spring.xml file in application and I am using springProperties like in the example below

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProperty name="event.pattern" source="my.logging.event.pattern"/>`

Values of my springProperties are set in spring cloud config .yml file

```
my:
  logging:
    activated: true
    appender:
      waitStrategyType: sleeping
    encoder:
      includeCallerData: true
      includeMdc: false
    event:
      maxSize: 15000
      pattern: |
        {
          "message": "%.-${my.logging.event.maxSize}msg",
          "req": {
            "url": "%mdc{req.url}",
            "headers": {
                "x-request-id": "%mdc{req.headers.x-request-id}"
            }
          },
          "application": {
            "name": "${spring.application.name}"
          }
        }
```

Unfortunetly I am getting error when I start my app:

```
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider@44a2b17b - Failed to parse pattern [event.pattern_IS_UNDEFINED] com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'event': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

It is because logback-spring.xml is read before externalized configuration

What will be the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your **loback-spring.xml** to **myConfig.xml**

Add this in your application.yml

```
logging.config: classpath:myConfig.xml
```

it works for values defined in "application.yml", but may still be too early for spring-cloud-config.